# Pdf and Cdf of a Random Process

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

A random process increases linearly with time: Y(t) = at + X, where a is a
constant and X is uniformly distributed on [−1, 1]. I appreciate it if you can help me how I can find cdf and pdf of the random process of Y(t) for  = R+.
I also need to find the mean, variance, autocorrelation function, and autocovariance function for Y(t).

Comment: By inspection, $Y(t)\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(at-1,at+1)$.

Comment: What have you tried? It's important that you show some of your own work on the problem before others try to help you.